# SQL Server how to fetch single record from multiple resultset per condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table A which has multiple records per year. I would like to pick the latest record for the current year. If there is not record for current year, I would like to pick the record which has the latest value for the year field. Can someone help?

I have the below query in SQL Server 2008 V2.

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear INT
SET @CurrentYear = YEAR(GETDATE())
SELECT Account,
       COLUMN2,
       COLUMN3,
       YEAR_c
FROM   A WHERE YEAR_c = @CurrentYear
```

If there are multiple records in table A for current year 2017, this query will return all records. I would like select the latest record from this list. Also, I need to select one record for the combination of Account & Year_c.

Comment: Do you even need a comparison here? I think GROUP BY and MAX(Year_c) will get you what you need.

Comment: Or more likely, TOP 1 ... ORDER BY...

Comment: @Jacob, the group by and MAX seems to yield what I want. However, in my production example, I have nearly 40 columns in the select statement. By having the aggregate function MAX, I guess I need to include all fields in the group by clause, correct?

Comment: @JacobH, for additional fields in the select, I had to add those in the group by clause which does not fulfill my needs. Because of the other fields in the group by clause, I get multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query would return latest record per account:

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear INT
SET @CurrentYear = YEAR(GETDATE())
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY YEAR_c DESC) AS RN,
           Account,
           COLUMN2,
           COLUMN3,
           YEAR_c
    FROM A WHERE YEAR_c <= @CurrentYear
) AS Results
WHERE RN = 1
```

The trick is to select all records and assign them row-index per each account (partition), sorted by year descending.
Then select only ones with row-index of 1 which are the latest per account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. This seems to work and provide the results that I want. I will do some more testing and make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: Well, if you want the latest record per account, than this is it - no mistake. Done this hundreds of times.

Comment: As an alternative, you could just select account and year in the inner query. Then join with A in the outer query and select rest of the columns... might gain performance.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need an `TOP` and `ORDER BY` though this is usually done on a `DATETIME` column. Not just a `YEAR` column.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       Account,
       COLUMN2,
       COLUMN3,
       YEAR_c
FROM   A
ORDER BY 
       YEAR_c DESC
       ,Account
```

The `Account` in the `ORDER BY` is just a suggestion... since only ordering by the year could return different results each time

Or, one for each group...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Account,
       COLUMN2,
       COLUMN3,
       max(YEAR_c)
FROM   A
GROUP BY
      Account
      COLUMN2,
      COLUMN3,
```

Comment: I don't think TOP 1 is an option since I need one record per combination of Account and Year. TOP 1 will always fetch one single record for the entire resultset.

Comment: then aggregate all other columns. i posted an edit @BalajiPooruli.

Comment: thanks for the update. However, it does not seem to give what I want. To test this, I have tried the following at sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: thanks for the update. However, it does not give the result what I want. I want all columns corresponding to MAX(Year__c) for an account. The additional MAX() on other columns provide max values from other records for the same account.

Comment: Well, that would mean that you could have duplicates. How would you chose which one you would keep?

Comment: Yep, there are multiple records for a combination of Account and Year, I would like to select max(Year) for an account and select all corresponding fields from that record itself.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli based off that, then you only need max(year) and group by all other columns. I edited the bottom query.

Comment: Jacob suggested that only and that did not work out too. Since I had to include all the variables in the SELECT clause to the GROUP BY clause, it resulted in duplicate records.

Comment: if there are duplicate, then add `DISTINCT`. Anything further, you will need to provide some sample data and expected output. This is a guessing game at this point.

Comment: @Dusan, started working on this now. Is it possible to get rid of the RN column from the resultset?